# last local or current changeset id

Tags: tfs

This question is related to the last change set id available in TFS, my query is, our tfs collection has multiple branches. I create a work space for each branch and build them.

Now **my question is:** I wanted to know the last local changeset id of the workspace with which I build the solution.

For example, I build MAIN branch 2 days back, now I wanted to know the last local change set id that is available locally. I used ***History command*** but some how it is giving the server changeset not the local changeset id.

Here are my arguments

```
tf history  $/MAIN /collection:tfscollection /format:Detailed /sort:Descending /stopafter:1" ;
```

Comment: TFS only has one Changesset Id, there is no local or server.

Comment: but if u dont perform "getlatest" or getspecific option(i mean if u doesnt have latest version), then the local changeset id what u have will defer from  what u have in server right?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you want to look at the history of your *workspace version*.  TFS tracks (server-side) the versions of files you have locally and defines your *workspace version* to be the version of the files that you have locally.  Contrast that with the *latest version* which is the current version on the server.

You can use a [*version spec*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56f7w6be%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to indicate what version you want to query, `T` for the latest version and `W` for your workspace version.

Another problem, however, is that your current query will only look at the history for the folder you're specifying - that is, when it was added or branched.  You will need to perform a *recursive* query to example all changesets that affect (are beneath) the specified folder.

Thus, your query to get the latest version on the server becomes:

```
tf history $/MAIN /collection:tfscollection /version:T /recursive /stopafter:1 /format:detailed /noprompt
```

And to get your workspace version:

```
tf history $/MAIN /collection:tfscollection /version:W /recursive /stopafter:1 /format:detailed /noprompt
```

Comment: Hi Edward, I need little more information, if i specify the workspace of a branch , should i execute the program also from the same workspace? because i have two workspaces for main and my development branch. i execute the program from my development branch.In the program i have given the argument $/Main as a branch then it is giving no histories found in this combination..do u know the reason?

Comment: You'll need to use a mapped path if you want to use the workspace version.  If you have a development branch, you'll need to be in the workspace that contains that mapping.  Or you can specify the `/workspace` flag.